# How to search across multiple indices which have different kinds of documents using Nest ElasticSearch 6.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I've got two indices which each have their own kind(different shapes) of document, but I have a requirement where search results should include both of these types of documents.

From what I've read what I need to do is a covariant search across two indices, searching across multiple indices doesn't seem difficult at all, but I'm clueless about how to do the covariant search in Elasticsearch 6.x. All the other question's answers here is SO are for older versions, and the documentation on this is very limited.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/covariant-search-results.html

Answer (score 0):

In 5.x and below, covariant searches could be implemented by inspecting the type of each document, and deserializing to a corresponding .NET type. With [types being removed from Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/removal-of-types.html), covariant searches in 6.x become a little trickier, and we can essentially take one of two approaches

1. Use a common type that can represent both shapes of document and deserialize all properties of both types. This may be something like `Dictionary<string, object>` or Json.NET's `JObject`
2. Use a serializer that can deserialize derived types to a common base type, based on properties within the JSON. For example, using [Json.NET's TypeNameHandling to include a `$type` discriminator field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_serializing_type_information) within JSON that can be later used to deserialize to the correct type.